# SageMaker Studio Notebook Cell Continues Running After Training Job is Complete

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I have an issue where the cell that calls `fit` stalls out, even when the training job is "Complete" in `SageMaker > Training jobs`.

I've tried several examples, the simplest being [one that uses SM's library](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aws_sagemaker_studio/sagemaker_algorithms/linear_learner_mnist/linear_learner_mnist.html).

I copied the code exactly into cells in my SM Studio notebook, set up the kernel to Data Science and the instance to m5.xlarge (m4 used in example but doesn't exist in dropdown).

I run the block that calls `linear.fit({"train": s3_train_data})`, the job shows up as completed, but in the notebook the cell continues to run, and I am unable to execute any subsequent cells.

The only output I receive is: `2021-11-29 21:26:47 Starting - Starting the training job`

Considering this uses demo code, I feel like something's going wrong on a higher level.

What could be causing a SageMaker Studio notebook cell to continue running after the training job is complete?

**As per mod's request:**

Error message: there isn't one; the code cell stalls as described in the post

Desired outcome: For the notebook to not stall despite saying the training job was complete, as described in the post

Sample code: from the example I linked in the post

```
import sagemaker
bucket = sagemaker.Session().default_bucket()
prefix = "sagemaker/DEMO-linear-mnist"
import boto3
import re
from sagemaker import get_execution_role
role = get_execution_role()

import pickle, gzip, numpy, urllib.request, json

fobj = boto3.client('s3').get_object(
    Bucket='sagemaker-sample-files',
    Key='datasets/image/MNIST/mnist.pkl.gz'
)['Body'].read()

with open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(fobj)

# Load the dataset
with gzip.open("mnist.pkl.gz", "rb") as f:
    train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin1")
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (2, 10)


def show_digit(img, caption="", subplot=None):
    if subplot == None:
        _, (subplot) = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    imgr = img.reshape((28, 28))
    subplot.axis("off")
    subplot.imshow(imgr, cmap="gray")
    plt.title(caption)


show_digit(train_set[0][30], "This is a {}".format(train_set[1][30]))
import io
import numpy as np
import sagemaker.amazon.common as smac

vectors = np.array([t.tolist() for t in train_set[0]]).astype("float32")
labels = np.where(np.array([t.tolist() for t in train_set[1]]) == 0, 1, 0).astype("float32")

buf = io.BytesIO()
smac.write_numpy_to_dense_tensor(buf, vectors, labels)
buf.seek(0)
import boto3
import os

key = "recordio-pb-data"
boto3.resource("s3").Bucket(bucket).Object(os.path.join(prefix, "train", key)).upload_fileobj(buf)
s3_train_data = "s3://{}/{}/train/{}".format(bucket, prefix, key)
print("uploaded training data location: {}".format(s3_train_data))
output_location = "s3://{}/{}/output".format(bucket, prefix)
print("training artifacts will be uploaded to: {}".format(output_location))
from sagemaker.image_uris import retrieve

container = retrieve("linear-learner", boto3.Session().region_name)
import boto3

sess = sagemaker.Session()

linear = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    container,
    role,
    train_instance_count=1,
    train_instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge",
    output_path=output_location,
    sagemaker_session=sess,
)
linear.set_hyperparameters(feature_dim=784, predictor_type="binary_classifier", mini_batch_size=200)

linear.fit({"train": s3_train_data})
```

Answer (score 1):

One option you have here is to set the wait parameter ( Whether the call should wait until the job completes )  to false in the fit call to avoid the synchronous waiting for the training job to complete. You can instead have a loop that just checks for training job status at your desired .